# BuildConfig (or alternative) in Flutter

Tags: android, gradle, dart, flutter, buildconfig

I'm new in Flutter and I'm looking for something similar to generated *BuildConfig* class I know from classic Android development.

I'm using Gradle to generated some of the constants I need in my code.

I could find 2 *BuildConfig* files in my project, one in `project/build/app/generated/source/buildConfig/projectName/BuildConfig.java` and other one in library called `shared_preferences-0.2.5/android/build/intermediates/classes/debug.io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences/BuildConfig.java`.

I was able to write down a constant in first of *BuildConfig*, problem is, I cannot refer to it from my code.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What should the constants in the BuildConfig do? (don't know Android)

Comment: Buildconfig is quite similar to env variables that depends on the release mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter is not Android. BuildConfig has nothing to do with dart code.

So far, there's no such thing in flutter. What we currently do instead is having a different `main.dart` depending on the build mode.

For that you'll simply do `flutter build apk --release -t lib/main.release.dart` which will define `lib/main.release.dart` as your entry point to the application.

This way, you can instantiate a custom `InheritedWidget` that pass down configurations with different values depending on your build target.